# Is this haproxy question appropriate for serverfault?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Does this question meet the criteria for on topic for SF? It *is* home networking but with enterprise hardware and software so it felt like it was blurring the lines as I typed it out but I was curious to get a read from the crowd.

[How can I get haproxy to completely ignore SSL handshake errors?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1134840/how-can-i-get-haproxy-to-completely-ignore-ssl-handshake-errors)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this question is off topic

- Home use.
- Obsolete/Unsupported equipment.
- Bad Practices.

Thank you for bringing it to attention. If the moderation strike ever ends and if can be bothered I will cast down and close votes appropriately.

Comment: I can delete the question. Is there a more appropriate spot to ask such a question? Oh nevermind, I can't delete after it's been answered.